# Processwire Add css class to page

Tags: processwire

I there a possibility to add a classname to a page?
I can't figure out how to implement such feature or if it already exists.

I'm using Processwire 3.0.42.

Comment: https://processwire.com/talk/topic/12005-happycssclasses-let-you-dynamically-addremove-bodyclasses-on-the-go/ could also be interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put something like this in your template where the body is:

```
<body class="<?php echo $page->template->name; ?>">
```

That will give your page body tag a class equal to page template name.

Comment: I know, but I'd like to know if there's an options to give a single page an additional class without using the template name.

Comment: Do something like this: `<body class="page-<?php echo $page->id; ?>">`
Or you can create a special field, fill it in the admin and use:
`<body class="<?php echo $page->page_class_field; ?>">`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a page title in the same way.

```
<body class="<?php echo $page->name; ?>">
```

Don't be worried about adding a class to every page. The overhead of doing this is negligible.

If you wish to add a different class you would need to add a field to your template and append it to the code above.

Answer (score 0):

As always in ProcessWire, **everything** is under your control. Alternatives to @ivangretsky's perfectly good answer would include-

Simply include a conditional in your template file. (This doesn't scale well if you need to add other classes to other pages using the same template.)

```
<?php
  $bodyClass = '';
  if($page->id == 1021) $bodyClass = 'my-class';
?>

<body class="<?php echo $bodyClass; ?>">
```

NB Using $page->id is better than $page->name, for example, as the ID doesn't change while the name could.

You could also add a field to the page template definition. Add a field called something like 'Body Class'. Then use the content of that field in your template file.

```
<body class="<?php echo $page->body-class; ?>">
```

This will scale better than my other suggestion, and there are options in the ProcessWire backend to hide or partially hide the field during normal use if you don't want users messing with its value.

One 'gotcha' from the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters) to be aware of is that CSS identifiers, including class names and IDs cannot start with a digit, so you cannot *just* use $page->id.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of options and it depends on your needs and maybe imagination :-).

You can use page name, template name, page id, or maybe combination.

```
<body class="<?php echo $page->template->name; ?> page-id-<?php echo $page->id; ?>">

// Output
<body class="your-template-name page-id-1234">
```

This way you can target template, page, or both.

Or, as mentioned by @ivangretsky, you can add custom field to page. And again, you can combine this aproach with template name, etc.
It depends on your needs and what you want to achieve.

Notice:

> Using $page->id is better than $page->name, as the ID doesn't change while the name could. @DaveP